# UILocalNotification repeat alert 2 minutes later

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, repeat, localnotification

I just want to but sure I'm understanding this correctly.
It looks like the only way to have an UILocalNotification repeat ONLY ONCE 2 minutes after the first one is to schedule 2 separate local notifications.
Is that right?
I have seen posts similar to these:

[How do I create a UILocalNotification that notifies every two minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6895101/454404)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4923276/454404

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4022779/454404

They all seem to suggest the "schedule 2 notifications" route.
The Apple docs clearly say that you use Calendar units for repeats. So I guess you could set one to repeat a certain number of seconds after but then you would have to cancel it.
It just seems like there must be a better way.

Thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Have not found a better way that this.